# What's the best way to separate the routes in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I did a small task with routes, in which when I put `/` in URL it redirects me to the login page and when I put `/dashboard` it redirects me to dashboard having material UI persistent drawer. But I did it the completely wrong way as I used browserRouter in 2 components but ideally, it should be only in the root component and because of this
*when I click on some link in my drawer for the first time it renders that component in the dashboard but when I refresh the page it loads nothing*
I saw an example **[here](https://minimals.cc/auth/login)** routes are quite well organized like when I click on login their URL is `auth/login` when I signup their URL is `auth/signup` and the same goes for the dashboard when I go to dashboard their URL is `dashboard/app` and when I click on other link items the pattern goes same `dashboard/link`.

Please see the above example to understand what I am trying to explain.

You can see my code **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-with-drawer-9fpmw?file=/src/App.js)** on codesandbox too

**Inshort:** I want to organize my routes in such a way `auth/login` `auth/signup` `dashboard/app` `dashboard/profile` etc.

**My App.js**

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import AppDrawerBar from "./compponents/AppDrawerBar";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={AppDrawerBar} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Login = () => {
  return <h1>Login Page</h1>;
};

export default Login;
```

**Dashboard.js where links contain routes for home component by default and about compoenet**

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import About from "../pages/About";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
              edge="start"
              className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
              Persistent drawer
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              ) : (
                <ChevronRightIcon />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            <ListItem button key="home" to="/home" component={Link}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <MailIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Home" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            <ListItem button key="about" to="/about" component={Link}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <InboxIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="About" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main
          className={clsx(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open
          })}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </main>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return <h1>Home Page</h1>;
};

export default Home;
```

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";

const About = () => {
  return <h1>About Page</h1>;
};

export default About;
```

Comment: So you've 2 root paths, "/dashboard" and "/", and a handful of components... have you tried defining specific routes for each path for each component you want rendered? What have you tried?

Comment: @DrewReese, I am learning to react routes so still I don't know many things. Yes, two root paths. You can see it here in app.js what I tried, its some simple routing while other routes in components/dashboard at line 97... https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-with-drawer-9fpmw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to create nested routes, i.e. you want the `About` component rendered on a nested route in the "/dashboard" sub-domain, like "/dashboard/about".

## Issues

You've wrapped the `AppDrawerBar` component into a second, nested Router. This can mess with the overall app routing as the outer router wrapping the app isn't made aware of anything the nested inner routers are handling. It also doesn't nest the route paths.

## Solution

1. Create a new `Dashboard` component to act as a "landing" page and manage nested paths. You'll want to also move the `AppDrawerBar` here since that is what handles your nested route navigation.

   ```
   import { Switch, Redirect, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
   import Home from "./Home";
   import About from "./About";
   import AppDrawerBar from "../components/AppDrawerBar";

   const Dashboard = () => {
     const { path } = useRouteMatch();
     return (
       <>
         <AppDrawerBar>
           <Switch>
             <Route path={`${path}/about`} component={About} />
             <Route path={`${path}/home`} exact component={Home} />
             <Redirect to={`${path}/home`} />
           </Switch>
         </AppDrawerBar>
       </>
     );
   };

   export default Dashboard;
   ```
2. Don't wrap `AppDrawerBar` with another `Router` and remove the `Route` components defined there. Instead, render passed children. Update the links to use `url` from the current route match to compute the nested links.

   ```
   function PersistentDrawerLeft({ children }) {
     ...

     const { url } = useRouteMatch();

     ...

     return (
       <div className={classes.root}

         ...

         <Drawer
           className={classes.drawer}
           variant="persistent"
           anchor="left"
           open={open}
           classes={{
             paper: classes.drawerPaper
           }}
         >
           <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
             <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
               {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
                 <ChevronLeftIcon />
               ) : (
                 <ChevronRightIcon />
               )}
             </IconButton>
           </div>
           <Divider />
           <List>
             <ListItem button key="home" to={`${url}/home`} component={Link}>
               ...
             </ListItem>
           </List>
           <Divider />
           <List>
             <ListItem button key="about" to={`${url}/about`} component={Link}>
               ...
             </ListItem>
           </List>
         </Drawer>
         <main
           className={clsx(classes.content, {
             [classes.contentShift]: open
           })}
         >
           <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
           {children}
         </main>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit whats-the-best-way-to-separate-the-routes-in-react-router-dom]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to learn and implement it. I really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    export default function Router() {
  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: <DashboardLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" />, index: true },
        { path: 'app', element: <DashboardAppPage /> },
        { path: 'user', element: <UserPage /> },
        { path: 'products', element: <ProductsPage /> },
        { path: 'blog', element: <BlogPage /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'login',
      element: <LoginPage />,
    },
    {
      element: <SimpleLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" />, index: true },
        { path: '404', element: <Page404 /> },
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <Navigate to="/404" replace />,
    },
  ]);

  return routes;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.